# R Hana authentication with Kerberos and ODBC JDBC

Tags: r, kerberos, hana, rodbc

I was trying to connect to Hana from R using JDBC. 
It gives the below error.

I have the kerberos setting `AuthMech KerberosFDQN` etc configured too.

Any clue possible root cause for this error

```
odbcconn <- odbcConnect("HD2")

Warning messages:
1: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=HD2") :
  [RODBC] ERROR: state 08S01, code -10709, message [unixODBC][SAP AG][LIBODBCHDB SO][HDBODBC] Communication link failure;-10709 Connection failed (RTE:[200106] Protocol error, invalid authentication packet (m_server_at_my_company.com:30050))
2: In RODBC::odbcDriverConnect("DSN=HD2") : ODBC connection failed
```